# Grouping array items based on string value

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to group an array by `sport`. It could be `n` number of sports. Finally, then create a new array with it. Is there an efficient way to this without going overkill?

```
$sports = [
    ['sport' => 'soccer', 'id' => 97487];
    ['sport' => 'soccer', 'id' => 244800];
    ['sport' => 'soccer', 'id' => 258740];
    ['sport' => 'basketball', 'id' => 147884];
    ['sport' => 'baseball', 'id' => 222240];
    ['sport' => 'baseball', 'id' => 222245];
];
```

Initial array:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sport"]=>
    string(6) "soccer"
    ["id"]=>
    int(97487)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sport"]=>
    string(6) "soccer"
    ["id"]=>
    int(244800)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sport"]=>
    string(6) "soccer"
    ["id"]=>
    int(258740)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sport"]=>
    string(10) "basketball"
    ["id"]=>
    int(147884)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sport"]=>
    string(8) "baseball"
    ["id"]=>
    int(222240)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sport"]=>
    string(8) "baseball"
    ["id"]=>
    int(222245)
  }
}
```

Desired results:

```
array(3) 
{
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["sport"]=>
          string(6) "soccer"
          ["id"]=>
          int(97487)
        }
        [1]=>
        array(2) {
          ["sport"]=>
          string(6) "soccer"
          ["id"]=>
          int(244800)
        }
        [2]=>
        array(2) {
          ["sport"]=>
          string(6) "soccer"
          ["id"]=>
          int(258740)
        }
    }
    [1]=> 
        array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["sport"]=>
          string(10) "basketball"
          ["id"]=>
          int(147884)
        }
    }
    [2]=> 
    array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["sport"]=>
          string(8) "baseball"
          ["id"]=>
          int(222240)
        }
        [1]=>
        array(2) {
          ["sport"]=>
          string(8) "baseball"
          ["id"]=>
          int(222245)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @JayBlanchard my apologies. I didnt know where to start. I will remember this for future reference. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the array like so:

```
$sports = [
    ['sport' => 'soccer', 'id' => 97487],
    ['sport' => 'soccer', 'id' => 244800],
    ['sport' => 'soccer', 'id' => 258740],
    ['sport' => 'basketball', 'id' => 147884],
    ['sport' => 'baseball', 'id' => 222240],
    ['sport' => 'baseball', 'id' => 222245]
];

// we will build an array here where the key is the sport
// name and the value is an array of objects pertaining
// to that sport i.e. 'basketball' => [bb1, bb2, ...]

$array = array();

// now consider every sport object in your original array

foreach($sports as $key => $item)
{
   if (array_key_exists($item['sport'], $array)) {
     // we encountered this same sport in the past so we
     // know $array['sportName'] already exists and can
     // push right to it
     $array[$item['sport']][] = $item;
   } else {
     // we have never seen this sport before and now must
     // insert the sport into $array['sportName'] = []
     // and push this sport object to it
     $array[$item['sport']] = [$item];
   }
}

// since $array's keys are the names of the sports themselves, but
// you want the keys to be numeric, this will build a new array
// from just the values of $array which at this point contains
// grouped arrays of sport objects

$result = array_values($array);

// print the results for good measure :)

print_r($result);
```

This works by looping over your sports array and building a second array of `[sportName => arrayOfThatSport]`. Inside the for loop, we are checking to see if a given sport already exists in this array. If it does, great, add the sport to the corresponding array for that sport. Otherwise, create a new array for that sport available at `$array['sportName'] = [sportObject]`. If you consider several iterations of the loop you will see that we're either always adding to an existing `$array['sportName']` array, or creating a new array at this position whenever we encounter a new sport we've never seen before. This gives us a final array similar to: `[ "sport
: [...], "sport2": [...] ]` but in your case you want a numeric array not an associative array, hence the call to `array_values`.

Comment: perfect solution

Comment: Great explanation and indeed a perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggested solution.

```
$groupedSports = [];
foreach ($sports as $item) {
    if (empty($groupedSports[$item['sport']])) {
        $groupedSports[$item['sport']] = [];
    }
    $groupedSports[$item['sport']][] = $item;
}
```

Short explanation:

- line 1: we initialize an empty array
- line 2: we start a loop on the original array
- line 3-5: if it's the first occurrence for the current sport, we initialize an empty array for that sport (avoid warnings)
- line 6: we assign current item to the appropriate array

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard you are right but I was just taking a break from a tedious job so I just enjoyed myself :-) I will now edit my question accordingly.